# reading 300k cells in excel using read_only in openpyxl not enough

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I've read quite a few questions on here about reading large excel files with openpyxl and the read_only param in load_workbook(), and I've done it successfully with source excels 50x30, but when I try to do it on a workbook with a 30x1100 sheet, it stalls. Right now, it just reads in the excel and transfers it to a multi-dimensional array.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook


def transferCols(refws,mx,refCol,newCol,header):
    rmax = refws.max_row

    for r in range(1, rmax+1):
        if (r == 1):
            mx[r-1][newCol-1] = header
        else:
            mx[r-1][newCol-1] = refws.cell(row = r, column = refCol).value


    return

ref_wb = load_workbook("UESfull.xlsx", read_only= True)
ref_ws = ref_wb.active 
rmax = ref_ws.max_row

matrix = [["fill" for col in range(30)] for row in range(rmax)]
print("step ", 1)
transferCols(ref_ws,matrix,1,1,"URL")
...
```

I only put the print("step") line to track the progress, but surprisingly, it stalls at step 1! I just don't know if the structure is poor or if 300k cells is too much for openpyxl. I havent even began to write to my put excel yet! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it also fail to print anything if you use the [basic read-only example](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/default/optimized.html) from the docs? If it was/is a simple 2D sheet, I'd probably just save as CSV in Microsoft Office and read it line by line in python

Comment: What are you intending to do with the data after reading? You may have a solution with `pandas`

Comment: Hi @Abbas, thanks for engaging! I'm really stuck here. I need to read in a large 2D excel sheet, clean the data so that all the entries are in uniform format, and then save it. Pretty simple, yet resource intensive? The follow-on code is just multiple calls of transferCols(). I thought reading the Excel and storing it in a local 2D Matrix while I edit it before i write it to excel would be faster.

Comment: I should also say that my code works on smaller versions of the exact source Excel. It is only when I run it on a large Excel (same format and data cells), that the program stalls.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have an undimensioned worksheet so `ws.max_row` is unknown. If this is the case, use `ws.calculate_dimensions()` will tell you, then you should just iterate over the rows of both sheets in parallel.

Comment: When I run a test line print(ws._calculate_dimension()) i get     

Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/XLCleaner.py", line 319, in <module> print(ref_ws._calculate_dimension())

File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/read_only.py", line 214, in _calculate_dimension
    max_col = max(max_col, cell.column)
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() > int()   

What's curious is that ws.max_row returns the appropriate amount of rows from the excel sheet - 11,000. When I simply delete all the rows to leave 50 rows, the program runs as advertised.

Comment: Looks like a possibly corrupt file. You can't delete rows from a read-only file so I don't know what you mean. In any case, with only 11,000 rows you'll be fine keeping everything in memory. Or rewrite your code to use `ws.iter_rows()`. I can't make much sense of your code.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I meant, to test my code, I went in manually into MS Excel and deleted the rows to make it less of a load. Once I validated that my code worked, I ran it on the original excel sheet of 11,000 rows - which it stalls at. @Charlie Clark. I appreciate the try

Comment: Well, Excel will recalculate the sheets dimensions so openpyxl has something to work with. If you look at the source of the relevant file the dimensions tag is probably incomplete or missing. Sounds incomplete from your description.

Comment: Thanks @Charlie Clark.  Do you mean seek the dimensions from within Python (maxrows, max columns), or is there some dimensions tag in excel that I dont know about? The ws.max_rows and ws.max_columns return the appropriate amount.  I really appreciate you sticking with me with this haha.

Comment: Worksheets have an optional `dimension' tag. openpyxl does not rely on this read a file and will simply read in as many rows as there are, or the limit you set. On the openpyxl mailing list I have described how you can do this in parallel with two worksheets.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of trying to read large excel in `openpyxl` try [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) shall get you better result. pandas has better functions to clean the data that you are ought to do.

Here is an example of 10000 rows and 30 columns of data that is written and read back in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000,30))
df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
df1 = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
```

Comment: Pandas internally uses the `xlrd` library to read Excel file. Depending upon what you want to do, and this is one of the cases, openpyxl's read-only mode is better suited.

Comment: @CharlieClark while `openpyxl` read-only mode is better suited, OP is unable to read his/her excel with 300K+ cells using it, while this is an example showing how `pandas` works with reading 300K cells.

Comment: No, there is no problem reading the file and the size is not relevant here. The code used relies on an optional optimisation which puts the dimensions of the sheet at the start of the XML. If this is missing then ipso facto you cannot use it but the cells can still be read. Also, as noted above: openpyxl can easily handle 300k cells in memory.